Ubuntu Server unreachable via SSH after some amount of time
I have Ubuntu Server 22.04 running at home. It has a static IP, outside of DHCP range so the IP will not change. Also, my home network's public IP has been the same the whole time.
When the server is freshly booted up/restarted, I can SSH into it just fine. I can terminate the session and reconnect without any issues.
However, if it's been a few hours without connecting to it, the connections fail. Is this a common problem for servers? I'm wondering if the SSH server shuts down after some amount of time with no connection attempts? Or maybe the server suspends itself.

Checking if ssh/sshd is still running on the server would be an excellent first step. Servers aren't usually supposed to go dark after a few hours, can you still ping it (if you could before)?


if it's been a few hours without connecting to it, the connections fail. Is this a common problem for servers?

No, for me at least, that is extremely uncommon.
The only time I have seen something similar was with a very old version of sshd that was exposed to the Internet through port forwarding. It was locked down pretty tight - no root access, public-key authentication only, a handful of specific users only and so on. When probing bots held their connection open during authentication, the sshd didn't time them out quickly and so sometimes would run into its configured limit on active connections and would be unable to accept genuine clients for a while. I don't think recent versions of sshd have this kind of issue though.

When the server is freshly booted up/restarted, I can SSH into it just fine.

I would always prefer to use something like sudo service sshd restart than restart the whole OS. It is almost always faster, equally effective and far less disruptive.
For this sort of issue I typically investigate the cause by checking the service status and reviewing the relevant log files, e.g. starting with sudo grep sshd /var/log/auth.log | tail -n 30 and similar.
